# How to identify the DOM node proximity

Tags: java, html, dom

Lets say I have a set of nodes A,B,C,D and a node say X. Now I need to find the proximity of A,B,C,D with respect to node X. (Using Java)

So that I can get to know which of the node from the given set of nodes is nearest to node X.

**EDIT :**
 Let say, a HTML has a node called DOB (Node X). I have *regex* pattern [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} for that Node DOB, to represent the value of DOB which will possibly in text node. Now I will search given HTML DOM to look for the text node which satisfies the *regex* pattern.

Now the nodes which satisfies the pattern will be more than one.Assume there is a *Account Opening Date*,*RepairDate* nodes are there in the HTML.So there will be three text nodes which will be satisfying the pattern.Now I need to identify which of the three text nodes is corresponds to Node DOB?

Comment: Proximity in the DOM tree? Euclidian distance on an HTML page?

Comment: I don't know if I understood well, but you could try to count the nodes. For example, from node A to node X, how many nodes? So, you can compare the quantity. Do you have any code?

Comment: I don't have code,first I need to decide on approach. Among A,B,C,D which one is nearest to node X?

Comment: Joe, If Euclidian distance achieved here, then I can compare the distance and get to know which node is nearest to node X

Comment: Is there some specific structure in this (eg the nodes are siblings or some node can be a parent/child of X) or no structure at all (you can find any node anywhere)? Moreover you talk about nodes, and not elements. Does that include textnodes too?

Comment: By proximity you mean number of nodes between X and any given node?

Comment: @Murugesh you need to clarify the word "nearest" before we can give you more help.

Comment: @alkis, Yes the given nodes can be siblings or can be parent but not always.It includes textnodes also.

Comment: @Joe, Nearest means here, while the page renders which of the nodes A,B,C,D comes adjacent or just below to the node X.

Comment: You really should edit your question and include some detailed examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have calculated the XPath of an node X and {A,B,C,D} . By comparing the Node X's Xpath  with A,B,C,D nodes XPath, got the Node which has most common XPath elements with Node X among all and that node is nearer to Node X